# C++ problem with storing objects in a list

Tags: c++, list, oop, c++11

This is my code:

```cpp
class Student {
   
    const std::string& Name;
    const std::string& Pinfo;
    std::map < std::string, float > Ngradelist;
    
public:

    Student(const std::string& n, const std::string& p, std::map < std::string, float > Ng) :
            Name(n), Pinfo(p), Ngradelist(std::move(Ng)) {}

    virtual void Display() {
    
            std::cout << "Name: " << Name << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Personal information: " << Pinfo << std::endl;
            std::cout << "NCourse:" << std::endl;
            for(const auto& it : Ngradelist)
                std::cout << "   " << it.first << "   Grade: " << it.second <<  std::endl;
        }
    };

    void InsertListaStudenti(Student& student, std::list < Student > &listaStudenti) {

        listaStudenti.push_front(student);
    }



int main ()  {

    std::list < Student > listaStudenti;

    unsigned short option = 10;

    while(option != 0) {

        std::cout << "1.Add student." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "4.Display Student." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "0 is for exit." << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Option is : ";

        std::cin >> option;
        switch  (option) {

            case 0 : {

                std::cout <<" You chose to leave.";
                exit;
                break;
            }

            case 1 : {

                std::string name , pinfo, course;
                float grade = 0;
                std::cout << "Insert name : ";
                std::cin >> name;
                std::cout << "Insert personal information : ";
                std::cin >> pinfo;
                std::cout << "Insert course : ";
                std::cin >> course;
                std::cout << "Insert grade : ";
                std::cin >> grade;
                Student student(name, pinfo, {{course, grade}});
            //    listaStudenti.push_back(student);
               InsertListaStudenti(student,listaStudenti);
                break;
            }
            case 4: {

                for(auto &it : listaStudenti)
                    it.Display();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine without using a list where I store these data. When I add one student,  there is no problem, but when I add the second student, the `Name` and `Pinfo` from the first student will change to the `Name` and `Pinfo` of the second student.

I'll give an example so you can understand maybe better:

Student 1 has these data: `Name=a`, `Pinfo=a`, `Course=a`, `grade=1`.
Student 2 has these data: `Name=b`, `Pinfo=b`, `Course=b`, `grade=2`.

If I want to display, it would be like this: student 1 will have b b a 1, and student 2 will have  b b b 2

Does anyone know what can I do to make this work? I believe that those 2 fields (`Name` and `Pinfo`) are overridden every time I create a new object in the main, but I'm not sure about it...

Answer (score 2):

This is how you define the `Student` members:

```
const std::string& Name;
const std::string& Pinfo;
```

You declare them as *references*, which means they will reference the original variables in your `main` function. And that will lead to *undefined behavior* as the life-time of those variables are limited and the original strings will cease to exist.

Use plain non-reference (and non-const) variables instead:

```
std::string Name;
std::string Pinfo;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I changed  and it works now. If you use const and & can you make it work or it's an inefficient way to do that, or it can't work like that.. ?

Comment: @MihaiIanculescu It doesn't work like that, when the original variables in the limited scope inside the `main` functions are destructed, the references you have become invalid immediately.